# ReactGrid: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollableElement')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having an issue with ReactGrid where I am receiving a "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollableElement')" error whenever I double click a cell. I'm not sure where this comes from or what causes it. Everything else works fine (cell selection, functional keys, everything) until I double click a cell, then this error is rendered on the page. Not sure what to do but would love any help

Tried:

- Searched the documentation for any mention of a type for "scrollElement", to no avail
- Switched from jsx to tsx file type
- Copy and pasted example code

Expected:

- Edit tile for selected cell rendered on page

Result:

```
Error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollableElement')" Rendered on page
```

Reproduction Steps:

1. `import @silevis/reactgrid`
2. copy example code
3. enable legacy-peer-deps for react 18 project to use react 17 package

Comment: @MichaelSeltenreich I've got the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, ended up not using ReactGrid

Answer (score 0):

Remove **"<React.StrictMode>"** from index.js.

From this:

```
<React.StrictMode>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
</React.StrictMode>
```

to this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: This does not solve my issue

Comment: Can you put your code in codesandbox?